# Is it possible to load a view that requires a user id, without determining it in the URI in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, uri, laravel-5.1

I'm continuing my adventure with Laravel 5.1. I have a small project I'm working on and I'm looking to find a nice way to load a User's gecko ideally without having the user id in the URI.

This is my current URI which works as it is:

```
Route::get('gecko/{user_id}/{name}', 'GeckoController@show');
```

As you can see i'm holding the user id in the URI and then i'm querying it to find the right gecko. As shown below:

```
public function show($user_id, $name)
{
    $name = str_replace('-', ' ', $name);

    $gecko = Gecko::where(compact('user_id', 'name'))->first();

    return view('gecko.show', compact('gecko'));
}
```

So to get this to work, I would do `project.dev/gecko/1/Zilly` - It works, but having the User ID in there kind of sucks. I decided that having the User ID was important in case there were multiple users who have geckos with the same name.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated, and if you need any extra code let me know :)

Andy

Comment: You can make a slug from user's name so it would be unique and you could remove id parameter from url. Otherwise I don't see any proper solution.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, I think I need to workout how to use the username instead of user id, and then somehow create a relationship between username and user_id in the database

Comment: Or... as the user has to be authenticated to get to this page, could I utilise the current authenticated user id to match it. So drop the id from the URI and use the auth id behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use username instead of user_id:

Routes:

```
Route::get('gecko/{username}/{geckoname}', 'GeckoController@show');
```

Controller:

```
public function show($username, $geckoname) {
    $user_id = User::where('username', $username)->first()->id;
    $geckoname = str_replace('-', ' ', $geckoname);

    $gecko = Gecko::where(compact('user_id', 'geckoname'))->first();
    return view('gecko.show', compact('gecko'));
}
```

If the user authenticated you can use `Auth::user()->id` and you should add only the gecko id.

For example:

Routes:

```
Route::get('gecko/{gecko_id}', 'GeckoController@show');
```

Controller:

```
public function show($id) {    
    $gecko = Gecko::find($id)->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
    return view('gecko.show', compact('gecko'));
}
```

If you would like to use `geckoname`:

Routes:

```
Route::get('gecko/{geckoname}', 'GeckoController@show');
```

Controller:

```
public function show($geckoname) {   
    $gecko_id= Gecko::where('geckoname',$geckoname)->first()->id; 
    $gecko = Gecko::find($gecko_id)->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
    return view('gecko.show', compact('gecko'));
}
```

Comment: How can i do this where i use the gecko name instead of it's id?

Comment: I edited my answer. Would you like to use authenticated user id and gecko name?